# How to compute the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(n+2)7^n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to compute the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(n+2)7^n}}$$
It's easy to prove that the series converges using comparison test but how to compute it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^r}r$$

Set $n+2=h$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{(n+2)7^n}=\sum_{h=2}^\infty\dfrac{(1/7)^{h-2}}h=49\sum_{h=2}^\infty\dfrac{(1/7)^h}h=49\left[\sum_{h=1}^\infty\dfrac{(1/7)^h}h-\dfrac17\right]$$

$$=49\left[-\ln\left(1-1/7\right)-1/7\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$ S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n+2}. $$
Your sum is $S(1/7)$. Then
$$ x S'(x)+2 S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+2)x^{n}}{n+2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} $$
An integrating factor for this differential equation is $x$, so we find that
$$ (x^2S)' = \frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x}-1 \\
x^2 S = C-x-\log{(1-x)}, $$
and setting $x=0$ implies that $C=0$. Hence
$$ S(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2}(x+\log{(1-x)}), $$
so
$$ S(1/7) = -49\left( \frac{1}{7} + \log{\left( \frac{6}{7} \right)} \right) $$